# Bitwise exclusive OR in Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, stored-procedures, bit-manipulation

In **SQL Server** I have been using the `^` symbol, however that doesn't seem to work in **Oracle**.

How do I do a bitwise exclusive `OR` in Oracle?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the docs:

```
function bitor(p1 number, p2 number) return number is
begin
  return p1-bitand(p1,p2)+p2;
end;

function bitxor(p1 number, p2 number) return number is
begin
  return bitor(p1,p2)-bitand(p1,p2);
end;
```

To see that these work, follow the logic with just 0s and 1s for input, and then not that there are no borrow or caries.

-- MarkusQ

Comment: xor = p1-2*bitand(p1,p2)+p2

Answer (score 5):

There is the BITAND operator:

```
select bitand(49,54)+0 from dual;
```

You can [build up the other operators](http://www.jlcomp.demon.co.uk/faq/bitwise.html) from it.

Answer (score 4):

There's no easy way.

You may cast string `HEX` values into `RAW` values and use `UTL_RAW`:

```
SELECT UTL_RAW.bit_xor(HEXTORAW(TO_CHAR(1, 'FMX')), HEXTORAW(TO_CHAR(2, 'FMX')))
FROM dual

---
 03
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this for XOR in SQL:

```
--9 XOR 7 = 14
SELECT 7+9-2*bitand(7,9) FROM dual
```